# How to know BMW e46 AC type

Tags: ac, bmw

Apparently there are two types of air conditioning units - **IHKR** and **IHKA** - in BMW e39's. I'm curious whether there are different types in e46's and, if so, how do I find out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [this PDF](http://www.bmwtech.ru/pdf/e46/ST034/8%20Climate%20Control.pdf), it shows the difference and it's pretty easy to see.

This is the IHKA control in the e46. It is an automatic control.

[image: IHKA]

This is the IHKR control in the e46 (with the radio above it). It is a manual control.

[image: IHKR]